# I have a problematic Nvidia GPU (it shows lines on screen!), can I connect my monitor to integrated GPU, and use the dedicated one for Autocad

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

As in the title. My GPU has a serious problem as it shows lots of lines on the screen.

I can probably use the integrated graphics card to connect it to the monitor. But can I use the Nvidia GPU without connecting it directly to the monitor? (i.e., something related to the Nvidea Technology that uses both integrated and dedicated cards)?

I specifically want to use the power of the Nvidia GPU for Autocad, Sketchup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using your integrated graphics video ports cannot be powered/use-the Nvidia cards GPU/video-technology.

Are you sure the lines aren't being caused by the monitor, video cable, or even specific video ports on the graphics card? Can you see the lines in the BIOS/UEFI? The last question eliminates windows, drivers, settings from possibly causing it, AKA if problem is in BIOS/UEFI it's HW at fault.